# Dynamically naming a table in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, database-design

So I have a table that for some design reasons cannot use a foreign key to map to other entities. So I am working on a function that is called to safely delete entries from the media table. As it stands at the moment I have written the function to have basic functionality using this resource as my guide on how to dynamically insert a table name into a query (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). As it stands my query is written as follows

```
DECLARE
    rows_returned numeric;
    is_media boolean;
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM solo_media WHERE entity_id = row_to_delete;

EXECUTE "DELETE FROM $1  WHERE id = $2;" INTO rows_returned USING table_name, row_to_delete;
END;
```

And when it is ran (with table_name and row_to_delete being parameters being passed in) I get the error

> ERROR:  column "DELETE FROM $1  WHERE id = $2;" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "DELETE FROM $1  WHERE id = $2;"
>                  ^
>   QUERY:  SELECT "DELETE FROM $1  WHERE id = $2;"
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "safe_del" line 7 at EXECUTE statement

when calling it with

```
SELECT safe_del(tableName, rowNumber);
```

Comment: String literals in Postgres (and SQL) use [apostrphes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), not quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As Milen A. Radev pointed out I was using the wrong characters to identify my string, I switched it over to dollar escaped strings, and resolved the issues.